Custom Theme Layout and Customizable User Profile Menu
I have created a custom theme layout and I'm trying to use the Customizable User Profile menu. This is available using a standard theme layout following the instructions from the article below.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389941&type=1
How do I update my custom theme layout to make the Customizable User Profile menu available? I tried adding a "Show header" configuration property to see if that would trigger it's availability but it did not.
